# A subgroup of abelian torsion group with infinite exponent

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Take an abelian torsion group, with infinite exponent, say, G=C2+C4+C8+..+C2^k+.., where Cn is cyclic of order n. What is the subgroup S that is the intersection of all subgroups of G with infinite exponent? That seems to be characteristic in G, what does G/S look like? Would the answer be vastly different if G=C2+C3+C4+...+Cn+...?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: If $+$ denotes direct sum of groups (usually denoted as $\oplus$) then surely $S$ is the identity subgroup.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you are interested in this $S$?  It does not seem to be a very natural notion to me.  For most abelian torsion groups with infinite exponent $S$ will be trivial but there are some exceptions and it seems plausible that the exceptions could be classified.

Comment: Let H2=infinite sum of C2s, H4=infinite sum of C4s, etc. Then with G=H2+H4+..H2^k+.. , surely S would be nontrivial?

Comment: So i am now thinking that if x in is a nonidentity element of G, then there is always a subgroup of infinite exponent that doesn’t conain x, so that S is always just the trivial subgroup. Oh well.